# PHP ZTS Container stops immediately

Tags: php, docker, zts

I am attempting to create a Docker container using the official PHP 7.4 ZTS image without making any modifications. However, when I start the container, it immediately stops as if the entrypoint is incorrect.

My Dockerfile contains the following content:
`FROM php:7.4-zts-alpine`

This is the result when I run `docker compose up`.

[image]

I have tried using other official ZTS images, but they also do not work.

Comment: Is `tty: true` in `docker-compose.yml` ?

Comment: It was not. It is not necessary for PHP FPM but it seems that is necessary for ZTS. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you put `tty: true` in the `docker-compose.yml`, you will be able to **keep the container running**. You can also do this by using the `-t` flag in the docker command.

The reason FPM doesn't require it to keep the container running is that FPM is the entrypoint.

With ZTS, bash is the entrypoint -- So, once you add a `tty: true` to the container, bash will be able to create interactive session and the container will (or at least should be) started with bash as the entrypoint.